# Arrays: create changed copy of array

Tags: ruby

I have an array:

```
array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,:value => 'value']
```

I want to create second array, who is the copy of first array minus `:value` element (addition: i don't know position of element exactly)

```
#expected result
array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,:value => 'value']
array2 = [1,2,3,4,5]

#my failure attempt
array2 = array1.delete(:value) # => nil
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
array2 = array1.reject{|a| a.is_a?(Hash) && a[:value]}
```

as @mu is too short said this will be safer:

```
array2 = array1.reject{|a| a.is_a?(Hash) && a.has_key?(:value)}
```

Or

```
array2 = array1 - {:value => "value"}
```

Comment: `array2 = array1.reject{|a| a.is_a?(Hash) && a[:value]}` works great! Thanks!

Comment: I think `array1.reject{|a| a.is_a?(Hash) && a.has_key?(:value)}` would be safer, you could get an `a[:value]` that was `false` or `nil` after all.

Answer (score 1):

If your array has a hash as one of its members (`array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,{:value => 'value'}]`) and you want to get rid of that member:

```
array2 = array1.reject{|a| a.is_a?(Hash)} # => array2 will equal [1,2,3,4,5]
```

If you want to get rid of a member that is a Hash and has a key of `:value`, you could add that to the reject block:

```
array2 = array1.reject{|a| a.is_a?(Hash) && a.key?('value')}
```

Comment: Ruby 1.9.x supports such arrays

Comment: Ruby arrays are heterogenius and can contain numbers, strings, other arrays, hashes and objects

Comment: `delete_if` will touch an original Array. You should use `reject` here

Comment: You're correct.  I have ammended my answer.  array2 = array1.reject{|a| a.is_a?(Hash)} method will still work if that is what is being asked.

Comment: But he don't need to change `array1` so `array1 == array2`.

Comment: But what if he have got a number of hashes and he wants to remove only one of them?

Answer (score 0):

Seems easy :

```
array2 = array1[0..-2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you aren't sure that the array has a :value key at the end and be sure that only :value is deleted :

```
array1.delete(:value)
```

Comment: you'd better edit your prev answer. and it won't work. `array.delete(:value => 'value')` will, but it is not Vladimir wants

Comment: Yes, it is this case that i meant, but `array2 = array1.delete(:value) # => nil'

Answer (score 0):

Another clean solution IMHO is to pop if last element is a hash :

```
array1.pop if array1.last.is_a?(Hash)
```

Comment: 1. pop will change original Array. 2. what if our Hash is not the last one?